# XMLHttpRequest cannot load url. Method PUT is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Methods in preflight response

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax

I am using angularjs `$http` for ajax request. It is working fine with `get` and `post` but giving error in case of `put`.

**Response Header :**

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Accept-Encoding, Accept-Language, Host, Referer, User-Agent, X-API-KEY
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Access-Control-Max-Age:1728000
Content-Length:0
Date:Mon, 25 Jan 2016 08:44:05 GMT
Server:spray-can/1.3.2
```

**Request Header :**

```
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,hi;q=0.6
Access-Control-Request-Headers:accept, content-type, x-api-key
Access-Control-Request-Method:PUT
Connection:keep-alive
Host:localhost:8080
Origin:http://localhost:8000
Referer:http://localhost:8000/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.111 Safari/537.36
```

Comment: how much do you know about CORS and preflight etc

Comment: @JaromandaX , my server url is localhost://8080 and client url is localhost://8000. when I am sending request from my server url it is working fine but when I am sending request from client url it is not working. It is something regarding cross domain that I know. How can I resolve it ?

Comment: @AnshulShukla you need to configure CORS in your backend webserver to accept requests from client server which runs on 8000. Since they sit on a different port, it's considered a Cross Origin Request.

Comment: `Access-Control-Allow-Methods:OPTIONS` - consider adding `PUT` to the list of allowed methods

Answer (score 5):

Try to setup following headers:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, Authorization, X-Auth-Token');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, HEAD, OPTIONS');
```

Comment: Simple and powerfull!